# is it possible to interupt navigation events to test link target with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visio

I would like to interrupt navigation events in a web page using javascript (jQuery ideally) to verify that the link works before the navigation happens.

Background: this is for verify links in Visio diagrams printed to web pages.. so the navigation instruction will be coming from JavaScript not an HTML element AFAIK. I am trying to avoid having to learn how the Visio generated page to achieve this, so I am hoping it can be done in a generic way by interrupting the navigation, and trying to load the page before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if you need to add links dynamically too:

```
$("a").live("click", function () {
    return testUrl($(this).attr('href'));    
});

function testUrl() {
   // return false if not valid;
   // else return true;
}
```

Returning false will stop the event's default behavior.

Comment: unfortunately the navigation is not generated by clicking on a link, instead it is raised by javascript based on a location you click on (AFAIK)

Comment: If you post the code I can revise my advice for you. But without the code I can only make more assumptions.

Comment: there are several files used to generate the page.. multiple HTML and JS files.. thanks for the help but I was more wondering if there was a generic way to interrupt navigation so I didn't have to dig into the generated code.  there is no upload feature for attachments on stackoverflow is there? i could upload an example of what visio generates..

Comment: in the end i dug into the generated code and modified it. its not explicitly said in your answer that there is not an event that one can intercept but you can do this:, could you maybe add something like that and i will mark it as the answer